# ActionScript Ranges?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Before I implement it by hand (simple, I know), I am wondering if ActionScript or Flex support ranges?

- You can do it in Ruby: `1..101`
- You can do it in .Net: `Enumerable.Range(1, 10)`

  Can you do this in AS3 or Flex?  I just don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't, but if you want, you can do something like this to emulate the syntax:

```
public class Range {
    public static function get(min:int,max:int):Array {
        var ret:Array = [];
        while(min <= max) {
            ret.push(min++);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
    for each(var i:int in Range.get(1,10)) {
        trace(i);
    }
```

Comment: The keyword 'get' cannot be used as function-name, since this the way to define getter function.

Comment: Yeah, implementing it is easy... I just wanted to know if it is in the framework or language is all... to avoid redundant code.

Comment: @Mark Knol. I didn't realize that and though I agree it's a good idea avoiding it, you're actually wrong. The above code compiles and runs without errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe their to be for populating an array. I checked the  `Array`, `ArrayUtil`, and `ArrayCollection` classes.

I know that the`TextInput` class has a property called `restrict` that you can specify a range like `0-9` or `a-Z`.

Also I found this for setting a charater range: [Setting Character Range](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e04.html)

But to populate an Array I think you may just have to build a method yourself.

Comment: But the `restrict` property of `TextInput` is a Regular Expression not a Range.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Array's *filter()* method to populate a new array from a specified range of objects from the principle array.

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Test extends Sprite
    {
    private var minRangeIndex:uint;
    private var maxRangeIndex:uint;

    public function Test()
        {
        var myArray:Array = new Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I");
        minRangeIndex = 1;
        maxRangeIndex = 4;

        var rangeArray:Array = myArray.filter(rangeCallback);

        for each    (var element:Object in rangeArray)
                    trace(element);
        }

    private function rangeCallback(element:Object, index:int, array:Array):Boolean
        {
        return (index >= minRangeIndex && index <= maxRangeIndex);
        }
    }
}

//traces:  B, C, D, E
```

using the *filter()* method you could actually create an array with several ranges (EX:  1-4 and 8-12) from a principal array in addition to any other type of filtering you would want, such as string matches for searching.